# Replacing an old supplier with new

Tags: function, plsql, count, cursor

A friend and I have been working on this basically it is supposed to determine if a new and old supplier id exit. The end game of this will be to take a old supplier_id and replace it will a new one. In the real world it would take suppliers you no longer use and replace them with ones you do. The script looks good to me but I keep getting a yellow line under the cursors selects.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION EX5B_SUPPLIER_EXIST 
(
  OLD_SUPPLIER_ID IN VARCHAR2 
, NEW_SUPPLIER_ID IN VARCHAR2 
) RETURN boolean AS 
cursor supplier_cursor is
 select count(*), 
(select count(*)as 
 from supplier 
 where supplier_id=new_supplier_id)+1 as new_id 
 from supplier 
 where supplier_id =old_supplier_id 
 group by supplier_id;
 supplier_row supplier_cursor%rowtype;
BEGIN
 open supplier_cursor;
 fetch supplier_cursor into supplier_row;
 if supplier_row.new_id > 1 then
 return true;

 else return false;
 end if;
 close supplier_cursor;
END EX5B_SUPPLIER_EXIST;
```

Comment: I forget to mention but it does compile.

Comment: What does a yellow line mean in your enviroment? In your query, "as" appear right after "count(*)" with no alias at all..

Comment: What happens when you run your function? Is that expected? (I'm assuming you're not asking to get the yellow line removed).

Answer (score 0):

Try by removing the as just after count(*). However keeping the as wont create any issue.